# How to install python packages without root privileges?

Tags: python, numpy, installation, scipy

I am using `numpy` / `scipy` / `pynest` to do some research computing on Mac OS X. For performance, we rent a 400-node cluster (with Linux) from our university so that the tasks could be done parallel. The problem is that we are NOT allowed to install any extra packages on the cluster (no `sudo` or any installation tool), they only provide the raw python itself.

How can I run my scripts on the cluster then? Is there any way to integrate the modules (numpy and scipy also have some compiled binaries I think) so that it could be interpreted and executed without installing packages?

Comment: I'm not really clear on exactly what you're asking--most Python modules are just Python code that you call `import` on.  If that's the issue, and you can't use `pip` or `easy_install`, you can just download the packages and stick them right in your Python `site-packages`, and then just `import` them.

Comment: @jdotjdot there're not only python code, but also compiled binary in the modules.

Comment: For `numpy` and `scipy` that is true.  But what do you mean by "can't install packages"?  What exactly is it that you're not permitted to install/put on the cluster?

Comment: @jdotjdot we're not permitted to `sudo`, and there's not any installation tool either.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for.  Looks like **David** provided a good answer already.

Comment: @jdotjdot Thanks for making my question clear.

Comment: Does the server have `pip` or `easyinstall`?

Comment: @ColonelPanic No, no any installation tool.

Comment: scipy might not be that easy to install, if the required dependencies (outside of python) are not installed

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need root privileges to install packages *in your home directory*. You can do that with a command such as

```
pip install --user numpy
```

or from source

```
python setup.py install --user
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143496/284795

---

The first alternative is much more convenient, so if the server doesn't have `pip` or `easy_install`, you should politely ask the admins to add it, explaining the benefit to them (they won't be bothered anymore by requests for individual packages).

Comment: **politely ask the admins to add it**, why didn't I think of that! OMG, we geeks suck...

Comment: @Skyler: asking the admins is *definitely* the best option! Based on your question I thought they might be opposed to it. (I do still recommend using virtualenvs once pip is installed, which incidentally might also serve as a solution to [this other question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems)).

Comment: This should have been `python setup.py install --user`. See https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#id37

Answer (score 12):

You could create a virtual environment through the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package.

This creates a folder (say `venv`) with a new copy of the Python executable and a new `site-packages` directory, into which you can "install" any number of packages without needing any kind of administrative access at all. Thus, activating the environment through `source venv/bin/activate` will give Python an environment that's equivalent to having those packages installed.

I know this works for SGE clusters, although how the virtual environment is activated might depend on your cluster's configuration.

You can try installing `virtualenv` on your cluster within your own site-packages directory using the following steps:

1. Download virtualenv from [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/archive/develop.zip), put it on your cluster
2. Install it using `setup.py` to a specific, local directory to serve as your own site-packages:

   ```
   python setup.py build
   python setup.py install --install-base /path/to/local-site-packages
   ```
3. Add that directory to your PYTHONPATH:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/local-site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}"
   ```
4. Create a virtualenv:

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   ```

Comment: Thank you! How to install `virtualenv` without `sudo` or `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: @Skyler: You can install `virtualenv` on a system where you do have control, create the virtualenv there, and then transfer the files to the cluster (unless I'm mistaken, and I could be, you don't even need `virtualenv` to activate the environment, only to create it- the environments is activated using bash scripts). *However*, that works only if the system you are creating the virtualenv on is of the same OS and architecture as the cluster- you might need to do a lot of customizing.

Comment: @Skyler: On second thought, it might be easier to install `virtualenv` in a local site-packages directory (basically bootstrapping your way up based on what you can do). Try the approach in my edit (I haven't tested it at all so let me know what problems you run into on the way).

Comment: Hi David, the step 2 gives `error: install-base or install-platbase supplied, but installation scheme is incomplete`. Did I miss something?

Comment: You can also install the package virtualenvwrapper, it will install some new commands and you can create your virtualenvs with mkvirtualenv *envname*, and it will automatically activate it for you. http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: @Skyler: Sorry- try replacing `--install-base` with `--home`

Comment: @DavidRobinson BTW, some of the dependencies have been already provided with the cluster. I want to create a virtualenv by cloning the current local environment, so that I don't have to install them again. Is it possible? I posted another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185288/how-to-create-a-virtualenv-by-cloning-the-current-local-environment

Comment: @Skyler: unless you use the `--no-site-packages` option, the virtualenv already "inherits" all of the packages and dependencies installed on the full system by default. (Try it on your computer).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Does it inherit in a "copy" way? What if the outside environment changes in the future? P.S.: the `--home` works. and before step 4, the local path should also be added to `PATH` so that the `virtualenv` command could run.

Comment: @Skyler: I'm not 100% positive, but I think it does copy them.

Comment: For me this works with:
"python setup.py install --prefix=<DIR>"

This installs virtualenv's scripts to <DIR>/bin and the package goes to <DIR>/lib/python2.7/site-packages

For some reason, using --home instead of --prefix puts the package into <DIR>/lib/python/site-packages (without the python version number!)

Answer (score 1):

You can import a module from an arbitrary path by calling:

`sys.path.append()`

Answer (score 1):

The Python Distribution Anaconda solves many of the issues discussed in this questions.  Anaconda does not require Admin or root access and is able to install to your home directory.  Anaconda comes with many of the packages in question (scipy, numpy, sklearn, etc...) as well as the conda installer to install additional packages should additional ones be necessary.

It can be downloaded from https://www.continuum.io/downloads