# How to CLONE LOCAL python environment (+ALL packages) into virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I want to CLONE Python and ALL installed packages into virtual environment using virtualenv.

there are couple of answers here on Stackoverflow ([How to create a virtualenv by cloning the current local environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185288/how-to-create-a-virtualenv-by-cloning-the-current-local-environment)) - they recommend doing the pip freeze > 1.txt in local environment. And after this in virtual environment pip install -r 1.txt. But this way doesn't work. After running "pip install -r 1.txt" it says that "Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto==0.22.0 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages" and points to LOCAL packages. So, if I delete or upgrade LOCAL packages they will be changed in VIRTUAL one too.

I also tried to use options --always-copy --system-site-packages. No success. 
see the printscreen:
[image]

Even after ALL these steps my Virtual env is 17,6 Mb, but local is 290 Mb. I want the virtualenv to be 290 Mb too (or close to it) - an ABSOLUTE copy.

So, the question - how to do a FULL absolute copy of Python and ALL installed packages for the given moment using virtualenv? (OS - Windows)
Or may be you know some other way - not with virtualenv.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a question to see if I fully understand, but it might be the answer too.

In the first virtual environment *venv_1* you create the requirements.txt file. (venv_1 is activated)

Then you deactivate *venv_1* and create a second virtual environment *venv_2*

You activate *venv_2*

```
source ./path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

and then,

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So, are you activating the second virtual environment and installing into it?

I hope this is useful.

[UPDATE]...
Sorry, I misunderstood a bit. 
I didn't realise you did not start from a virtualenv. So, I have tried this on my Mac and I did have some problems with Matplotlib and something else BUT, I upgraded all my packages and then did a pip freeze > requirements.txt, then created a virtual environment and installed from the requirements file into the virtual environment and it worked. Sorry I can't help other than to say that it did work for me on mac. 
Good luck.

Comment: hi. No. there is NO first and second virtual environments. There is Python (LOCAL, usual Python with many modules) and I want to create ONE virtual environment which will be a FULL copy of Python that is installed on my PC (with ALL modules).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your environment already has all the libs that you are trying to install from your .txt file.

Because I got the same "requirement already satisfied" error and turned out that i was trying to installing the .txt file in the same env i clonned it from ;P