# How to install ipython notebook locally?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use ipython notebook. When I type `ipython notebook` in the command line, I get:

```
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
```

The problem is that I do not have root privileges on the system (I use Ubuntu). I think that there is a work around with virtual environment but I do not know how exactly to use it. Could anybody please help me with that? What sequence of the command should I execute to be able to use ipython notebook in my browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179941/how-to-install-python-packages-without-root-privileges might be what you are looking for.

Comment: installing virtualenv would require root permission if you don't follow the instruction above.
Virtualenv is a nifty skill to have. You should look at http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/ for that.

Answer (score 8):

After running `pip install ipython[notebook]`, you need to deactivate the virtualenv and then activate it again.

In other words:

```
$ deactivate
$ workon my-virtualenv
(my-virtualenv)$ ipython notebook &
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been headbanging over this behaviour a bit.

Comment: This is weird - it's the first time I've ran into this today, never had to do this before.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook
```

Comment: In the current two versions of Ubuntu (12.04, 13.10) ipython-notebook is only version 0.13, which is lacking in many features. The current stable version of notebook is 1.1, which will be included in Ubuntu 14.04. Until then it is better to install in from other sources.

Answer (score 2):

[Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) can handle all the IPython-related installation issues for you. It also installs itself in its own virtual environment along with lots of other useful tools like nose and numpy. It opens notebooks in it's own IDE so you can easily switch between your notebook, the IPython interpreter, and other Python scripts. I use it with Ubuntu 12.04 and have had good success with it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) as it's explained in the official docs?

http://ipython.org/notebook.html

```
pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

Answer (score 2):

pip install --upgrade ipython[notebook]

that fix the problem for me .... appear that --upgrade fix some dependence or something else ....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [adamdklein blog post](http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=416). It takes you step-by-step through how to setup ipython and other mathematical goodies in a virtualenv (using Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Install Ipython notebook using the following command

```
pip install jupyter
```

Or, install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Ipython notebook is included in the Anaconda package.

Reference:

[Installing Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Now Ubuntu wants to not support Python note book. You just need to install Jupyter notebook instead of python notebook where you can access Python also. Below is the command for installation of Jupyter notebook.

```
sudo apt-get install Jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal:

`pip install ipython[notebook]`