# Removing multiple python installations from os x

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, duplicates

The past years I have needed python occasionally, but I have been installing versions and packages blindly using all sorts of different methods (canopy, easy_install, pip,...). This has led to the following tragic result:

```
$ python
python             python2.7-config   python3.4-32       pythonw2.6
python-config      python3            python3.4-config   pythonw2.7
python2.6          python3-32         python3.4m         
python2.6-config   python3-config     python3.4m-config  
python2.7          python3.4          pythonw
```

Currently I want to start a new project, using a lot of different python modules. However, when installing packages like pandas (using `pip`) I am running into difficulties which are most likely caused by the sheer number of python installations on my machine.

My question now is how could I remove all these python installations and start afresh, **without** doing a complete OS re-installation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems). I know this is possibly the best solution, but due to other projects I am currently working on this is currently not an option for me.

Alternatively, how could I at least create a workable python environment in which I can install the modules I need for the version I am using.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Louis

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you want to remove version 2.6. You can do

```
which python2.6
```

this will return the location of python2.6 in your computer. Then you can remove it.

Keep in mind that Python 2.x is shipped with OS X, so I don't think that removing it totally is a good option.

I have never tried `virtualenv` but this might be useful : [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

Comment: definitely +1 for virtualenv, esp mkvirtualenv -p `which python2.6`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I had indeed heard that I should be careful not to remove the original python installation, but mainly because of this I was unsure of what I could and could not touch on my system. 

With regards to `virtualenv` you are suggesting that I simply leave my mess as it is and create a separate environment for python?

Comment: Basically yes. In that way you will have a clean new environment to develop. And if in the future you feel bold enough, you can then remove some of older your python versions