# RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv
```

Console:

```
>>> runfile('/Users/isaiahnields/.spyder2/temp.py', wdir='/Users/isaiahnields/.spyder2')
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
File "/Users/isaiahnields/.spyder2/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
import cv
File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>>>
```

System Info: OS X El Capitan, Macbook Air, 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 HMz DDR3

I have already attempted updating numpy. I had to add cv.py to the python2.7 folder in Spyder-Py2 is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 166):

Upgrade numpy to the latest version

```bash
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but WHY? This problem arises because there are two numpy installed. How does upgrade solve this issue?!

Comment: This does not fix for me: `Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: It might solve the problem if you import torch using your default python, which has an older version of numpy.

Comment: this worked for me when trying to import newly installed pytorch with `import torch`

Comment: This worked for me after uninstalling and reinstalling python

Comment: wow. it worked !!!! Never thought the solution could be so easy. Thanks :)

Comment: This works, but now I'm getting warnings: `UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.23.3`

Comment: @MAZDAK The "why" for this answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756785/733092.

Comment: Start debugging process from here!!

Answer (score 16):

Check the path

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

For me this was /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy So I moved it to a temporary place

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy \
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy_old
```

and then the next time I imported numpy the path was /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.pyc and all was well.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you

Comment: Worked, but needed to reinstall it with `pip install numpy -I` (the capital i argument says to install while ignoring the current installation which got moved).

Comment: Similar thing happened with me in Google Colab with a package called `clusterval`.  @GuillaumeChevalier 's comment helped me solve this.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had the same problem where an old numpy version was installed and i was unable to move or remove old numpy

Comment: Don't do sudo pip install !

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Although I did not use it with sudo, I don't think that is required.

Comment: I received an edit request to remove "sudo" and add some other parameters. I understand the editor felt that that would be a better answer - however I rejected that edit, because *this* is what worked for *me*, and that's all I'm sharing. If you have any other answer, please feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 14):

## upgrading numpy to rescue

numpy official document suggests users to do upgrade to solve this issue [1].

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

## but which version of numpy should I upgrade to?

You may upgrade to a version that is too new/old for your environment. I spent a long time trying to figure out which version of numpy is expected to be upgraded to when running into this error, and here is a list [2] of numpy versions with their corresponding C API versions, which may be useful for troubleshooting such an issue:

```py
# 0x00000008 - 1.7.x
# 0x00000009 - 1.8.x
# 0x00000009 - 1.9.x
# 0x0000000a - 1.10.x
# 0x0000000a - 1.11.x
# 0x0000000a - 1.12.x
# 0x0000000b - 1.13.x
# 0x0000000c - 1.14.x
# 0x0000000c - 1.15.x
# 0x0000000d - 1.16.x
# 0x0000000d - 1.19.x
# 0x0000000e - 1.20.x
# 0x0000000e - 1.21.x
# 0x0000000f - 1.22.x
# 0x00000010 - 1.23.x
# 0x00000010 - 1.24.x
# 0x00000011 - 1.25.x
```

- Before numpy release 2.0 (<=1.26), you can find the list [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.26.x/numpy/core/setup_common.py#L35-L51) [2].
- Since numpy release 2.0, you can find the list [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/67539a40cb13bad56a650809bf10a49e905a250d/numpy/core/meson.build#L32-L49) [5]
- Before numpy release 2.0 (<=1.26), the C API VERSION in numpy is tracked in three places according to [3]:

  - numpy/core/setup_common.py
  - numpy/core/code_generators/cversions.txt
  - numpy/core/include/numpy/numpyconfig.h
- The error is reported by numpy's source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bdec32181605c8179fd79624d14c1cf019de75af/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py#L79) [4]

## references

- [1] https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#c-api-incompatibility
- [2] https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.25.x/numpy/core/setup_common.py#L35-L51
- [3] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/dev/releasing.html#check-the-c-api-version-number
- [4] https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bdec32181605c8179fd79624d14c1cf019de75af/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py#L79
- [5] https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/67539a40cb13bad56a650809bf10a49e905a250d/numpy/core/meson.build#L32-L49

Comment: Thanks for including the compatibility list!!

Answer (score 4):

You are likely running the Mac default (/usr/bin/python) which has an older version of numpy installed in the system folders. The easiest way to get python working with opencv is to use brew to install both python and opencv into /usr/local and run the /usr/local/bin/python.

```
brew install python
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

Comment: Becareful! It might not be a good idea for you to install multiple versions of python. You may end up like this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue tonight. It turned out to be a problem where I had multiple numpy packages installed. An older version was installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7` and the correct version was installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`.

Additionally, I had `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. PYTHONPATH was finding the older version of numpy before the correct version, so when inside the Python interpreter, it would import the older version of numpy.

One thing which helped was opening a python session an executing the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
print np.__version__ 
print np.__path__
```

That should tell you exactly which version Python is using, and where it's installed.

To fix the issue, I changed `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. And I also setup a virtual Python environment using the [Hitchiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv), specifically the section titled "Lower level: virtualenv" . I know I should have setup a virtual environment in the first place, but I was tired and being lazy. Oh well, lesson learned!

**(Update)**

Just in case the docs are moved again, here are the relevant bits on...

**Creating a Python Virtual Environment**

Install virtualenv via pip:

```
$ install virtualenv
```

Test the installation:

```
$ virtualenv --version
```

Optionally, et the environment variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to change the default version of python used by virtual environments, for example to use Python 3:

```
$ export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
```

Optionally, set the environment variable `WORKON_HOME` to change the default directory your Python virtual environments are created in, for example to use `/opt/python_envs`:

```
$ export WORKON_HOME=/opt/python_envs
```

Create a virtual environment for a project:

```
$ cd my_project_folder
$ virtualenv my_virtual_env_name
```

Activate the virtual environment, you just created.  Assuming you also set `WORKON_HOME=/opt/python_envs`:

```
$ source $WORKON_HOME/my_virtual_env_name/bin/activate
```

Install whatever Python packages your project requires, using either of the following two methods.

Method 1 - Install using `pip` from command line:

```
$ pip install python_package_name1
$ pip install python_package_name2
```

Method 2 - Install using a `requests.txt` file:

```
$ echo "python_package_name1" >> requests.txt
$ echo "python_package_name2" >> requests.txt
$ pip install -r ./requests.txt
```

Optionally, but highly recommended, install `virtualenvwrapper`. It contains useful commands to make working with virtual Python environments easier:

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

On Windows, install `virtualenvwrapper` using:

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

**Basic usage of virtualenvwrapper**
Create a new virtual environment:

```
$ mkvirtualenv my_virtual_env_name
```

List all virtual environments:

```
$ lsvirtualenv
```

Activate a virtual environment:

```
$ workon my_virtual_env_name
```

Delete a virtual environment (caution! this is irreversible!):

```
$ rmvirtualenv my_virtual_env_name
```

I hope this help!

Comment: The document you linked to gives a 404 error. Could you update the link?

Comment: @user3243242 As you wish!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem do following:

**First uninstall numpy**

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

**Install numpy with** *--no-cache-dir* **option**

```
sudo pip install --no-cache-dir numpy
```

And to specify any specific version e.g. 1.14.2

```
sudo pip install --no-cache-dir numpy==1.14.2
```

Comment: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `--no-cache-dir` did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

This command solved my problem.

```
pip3 install --upgrade numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with quaternion module. When updating modules with conda, the numpy version is not up^dated to the last one. If forcing update with pip command pip install --upgrade numpy + install quaternion module by pip install --user numpy numpy-quaternion, the issue is fixed.
May be the issue is coming from the numpy version.
Here the execution result:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.__version__
1.14.3
>>>

(base) C:\Users\jc>pip install --user numpy numpy-quaternion
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (1.14.3)
Collecting numpy-quaternion
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/73/5720d1d0a95bc2d4af2f7326280172bd255db2e8e56f6fbe81933aa00006/numpy_quaternion-2018.5.10.13.50.12-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (49kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 581kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy-quaternion
Successfully installed numpy-quaternion-2018.5.10.13.50.12

(base) C:\Users\jc>python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy as np
>>> import quaternion
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem due to documentation inconsistencies.
This page says the examples in the docs work best with python 3.x:  https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html#intro , whereas this installation page has links to python 2.7,  and older versions of numpy and matplotlib: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

My setup was as such: I already had Python 3.6 and 3.5 installed, but since OpenCv-python docs said it works best with 2.7.x, I also installed that version. After I installed numpy (in Python27 directory, without pip but with the default extractor, since pip is not part of the default python 2.7 installation like it is in 3.6), I ran in this `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is` error. I tried many different versions of both numpy and opencv, but to no avail. Lastly, I simply deleted numpy from python27 (just delete the folder in site-packages as well as any other remaining numpy-named files), and installed the latest versions of numpy, matplotlib, and opencv in the Python3.6 version using pip no problem. Been running opencv ever since.

Hope this saves somebody some time.

Answer (score 1):

When all else fail, check with the following script and disable unwanted  python import path(s), or upgrade the package on those paths:

```py
python ./test.py
```

`test.py` content:

```py
import numpy as np
print(f'numpy version:{np.__version__}')
import sys

from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)

import tensorflow as tf
print(f'TensorFlow version: {tf.__version__}')
```

For my case, it was the outdated conda version in `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` that was messing things up :(

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install numpy -- user --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Worked for me.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

For those using anaconda Python:

```
conda update anaconda
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your matplotlib version.

Somehow I installed a dev version of matplotlib which caused the issue. A downgrade to stable release fixed it.

One can also can try `python -v -c 'import YOUR_PACKAGE' 2>&1 | less` to see where the issue occurred and if the lines above error can give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check your `$PYTHONPATH`. I had changed mine in `~/.bashrc` in order to get another package to work.

To check your path:

```
    echo $PYTHONPATH
```

To change your path (I use nano but you could edit another way)

```
    nano ~/.bashrc
```

Look for the line with `export PYTHONPATH` ...

After making changes, don't forget to

```
   source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to launch spyder. "RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa".
This error appeared once I modified the numpy version of my machine by mistake (I thought I was in a venv). If your are using spyder installed with conda, my advice is to only use conda to manage package.

This works for me:

```
conda install anaconda
```

(I had conda but no anaconda on my machine)
then:

```
conda update numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me :

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is very old, but I do believe there are still many facing similar problem as I did. I encountered the above reported error when I used Python3 in a Raspberry Pi micro-computer, which is running on Raspberry Pi OS.

This is perhaps due to missing some libraries when installed the Numpy module. I solved this problem following the suggestion in the Numpy website.
[**Solutions for Numpy Module Import Error**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html)

This Numpy troubleshooting website is really informative and provides cross-platform  solutions for Windows, Anaconda, Raspberry, etc. Perhaps, someone can first follow the suggestion in this Numpy official website in order to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I used `import pyopencl` and I did not want to upgrade numpy cause tensorflow requires old version of numpy so I solved it by simply:

```
python -m pip uninstall pyopencl && python -m pip install pyopencl
```

This way pyopencl was configured with existing numpy version and error solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with this problem for a long time, firstly you have to upgrade numby then try this code :

```
import numpy as np 
print np.__version__
```

if gives you different version from the new one , uninstall the numpy(the new version) and use this

```
print numpy.__path__
```

go to that old numpy and delete the file , then install new version again

Comment: Hi Esraa  The top-2 answers in this thread that say this, and duplicating answers is not recommended. When you reach [15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you will be able to "vote up" helpful answers. Take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and find new, well-asked questions.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

My `pip` is not work after upgrade, so the first thing I need to do is to fix it with

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/pip
```

Change the line

```
from pip import main
```

to

```
from pip._internal import main
```

Then,

```
 sudo pip install -U numpy
```