# numpy version error when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, runtime-error, tensorflow

I have executed `pip install` for tensorflow.

Under the python command line environment, when I tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I met the following errors:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have checked my `numpy` version using `print numpy.__version__`. It showed `"1.8.2"`. So, what should I do now? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you need to upgrade numpy.  Possibly `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: Yes, seems not a tensorflow-specific issue, FYI, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-a-but-this-version-of-numpy-is

Comment: I have tried "pip install --upgrade numpy". But it told me I have already installed with the latest version.

Comment: @ReadyOrNot please try my solution.

Answer (score 2):

From the error, it looks like you're running python 2.7 from `usr/local/bin`. There is a mismatch problem between your `numpy` version and `tensorflow` installation. I'd recommend you to install anaconda since it will make sure that correct version of `tensorflow` that is compatible with your `numpy` version be installed.

Once you have anaconda, then do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Before I read your suggestion, I tried another way, that is to compile TensorFlow from source in my environment. It works fine now.

Comment: @ReadyOrNot No problem, it's still less hassle to use anaconda distribution!

Comment: @ReadyOrNot I did the same you did, i.e., compiled tensorflow from source and created an env. Now even after I did a conda install tensorflow, it still going to the old tensorflow env: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

Comment: Ok. I think I solved it by deleting the tensorflow folder from the env.