# pip install can't find a package during build even though it's installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

During pip install of a local package, which uses custom code for building, I am getting the following error:

```
python3 -m pip install -vvv . 
...
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-g_w7p_yj
Building wheels for collected packages: mypackagename
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-2p3g08e0
  Destination directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-2p3g08e0
  Running command Building wheel for mypackagename (pyproject.toml)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 37, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8htpge2f/overlay/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 25, in run
    File "/myfolder/mypackagename/mycustominstaller/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
      import numpy as np
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mypackagename (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpivmip1g1
  cwd: /myfolder/mypackagename
  Building wheel for mypackagename (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mypackagename
Failed to build mypackagename
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mypackagename, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 429, in run
    raise InstallationError(
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not build wheels for mypackagename, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Remote version of pip: 23.3.1
Local version of pip:  23.3.1
Was pip installed by pip? True
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-build-tracker-thq7346g'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580730/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+build+dependency+numpy

Comment: Thanks @phd, that seems related but I got a different error and did not use pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pip now uses an isolated environment (`/tmp/pip-build-env-.../overlay/`) for installing, making it unaware of any installed packages.

Adding to the setup.py setup() function the `setup_requires=['numpy']` makes it aware of the declared packages.