# import fancyimpute Runtime and ImportError

Tags: python, numpy, import, jupyter

I tried

`pip install tensorflow`
it says it is incompatible with my numpy version(1.20.0)

Then I tried unistall numpy to required version numpy~=1.19.2

Then
`pip install fancyimpute`
It installed without any errors in AnacondaPromt
But it still not working in Jupyter Notebook

The Error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-e68ac4972d28> in <module>
     16 import tensorflow as tf
     17 import numpy.core.multiarray
---> 18 from fancyimpute import KNN

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from .solver import Solver
----> 4 from .nuclear_norm_minimization import NuclearNormMinimization
      5 from .matrix_factorization import MatrixFactorization
      6 from .iterative_svd import IterativeSVD

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\nuclear_norm_minimization.py in <module>
     11 # limitations under the License.
     12 
---> 13 import cvxpy
     14 
     15 from .solver import Solver

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 __version__ = "1.1.10"
---> 18 from cvxpy.atoms import *
     19 from cvxpy.constraints import NonPos, Zero, SOC, PSD
     20 from cvxpy.expressions.expression import Expression


~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\cvxcore\python\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # TODO(akshayka): This is a hack; the swig-auto-generated cvxcore.py
      2 # tries to import cvxcore as `from . import _cvxcore`
----> 3 import _cvxcore

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution right here
[Opencv/numpy issue: "module compiled against API version X but this version of numpy is Y"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756080/opencv-numpy-issue-module-compiled-against-api-version-x-but-this-version-of-n/49756785#49756785)

Here is the table and since my version is 1.19.5(0xd) now,
I uninstalled this version and installed 0xe version of numpy which is 1.20.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I upgraded NumPy by running `pip install numpy --upgrade`. It worked around for me.