A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in NumPy 2.0.0 as it may crash
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\tut2.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\imutils\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
AttributeError: _ARRAY_API not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\tut2.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\imutils\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\mohit\OneDrive\Desktop\Front End\Flask\pythonProject1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import


A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in NumPy
2.0.0 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0. Some module may need to
rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.
If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module. We
expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

I was trying to make a flask app that uses cv2 and imutils libraries of python in Pycharm. But there seems to be a problem in Pycharm.
The error seems to be on the lines of import statement :
import imutils
import cv2 

I watched a tutorial online about how to download cv2 and imutils , but even after downloading there seems to be a problem.
The error is about the upgraded version of Numpy which I don't understand why it is happening , as I am not using Numpy.
Still I upgraded the version of Numpy but It does not work.
I have tried multiple things the people have suggested but nothing is working I think i am not sure how to make a docker.
The problem can be something related to Pycharm. I am not sure.

"I am not using Numpy" -- OpenCV's Python bindings do.

How do you "compile" your modules with numpy?

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78636752/ive-installed-python-and-opencv-by-using-the-correct-commands-in-the-cmd-but-w

@PrathikKini do not deface a question like that. you removed most of the traceback and you added unwarranted double emphasis formatting. wrapping the code in a code fence makes the post sufficiently readable.

and again a question that involves flask in some way...

@chrslg What do you mean? Underneath, numpy is a C library (and the commonly used CPython is written in C as well, as are a number of standard Python libraries). So you may have other libraries written in C (or C++, maybe other languages) that implement binary Python modules (not unlike say zlib or sqlite standard libraries). OpenCV's Python bindings are one such library, and it happens to use numpy's ndarray to represent its own Mat datatype (and some more) in Python. It includes relevant numpy C headers, and links as necessary.

@chrslg And most of the OpenCV packages I've seen are pre-built, and from that point on, the numpy library installed needs to be compatible with the one OpenCV was built against. Somewhat related is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756785/3962537 | I would assume OP is not compiling anything, at most pip might be doing some of it, but I wouldn't be surprised it those were pre-built wheels, and the dependency spec of some of those didn't expect a 2.0 to appear and be incompatible? Hard to say.

Try using:
pip uninstall numpy

pip install numpy==1.26.4


It is still not working
The main problem comes when i import imutils and cv2

@MohitGupta after doing pip install numpy==1.26.4 . You need to restart your kernel then only it will work.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78641150/13086128

pip uninstall numpy       # uninstall existing numpy
pip install "numpy<2.0"   # install the latest numpy 1.x version


It is still not working The main problem comes when i import imutils and cv2

pip install "numpy<2.0"

This answer makes more sense than the more upvoted answer

This is a code-only answer. Can you explain more?

I am having the same issue while building a docker container and the solution I found was to use the latest versions of pandas and numpy.
ie
numpy==2.0.0
pandas==2.2.2

I was also using pyarrow and that then had an issue bc my version was older so I bumped that to the latest version as well and that resolved my issue
