A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in NumPy 2.0.0
I installed numpy 2.0.0

pip install numpy==2.0.0

import numpy as np
np.__version__
#2.0.0

then I installed:
pip install opencv-python

Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.8.0.76)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (2.0.0)

Then I did:
import cv2

I am getting this error:

A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.0.0 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/colab_kernel_launcher.py", line 37, in <module>
    ColabKernelApp.launch_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
    lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
    self.ctx_run(self.run)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
    self.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
    result = self._run_cell(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
    has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-c8ec22b3e787>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_import_hooks/_cv2.py", line 78, in load_module
    cv_module = imp.load_module(name, *module_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 217, in load_package
    return _load(spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_import_hooks/_cv2.py", line 78, in load_module
    cv_module = imp.load_module(name, *module_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: _ARRAY_API not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c8ec22b3e787> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import cv2

8 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 
    345 else:

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.



Try this   py -m pip install numpy

The latest one is 2.1.0

The solution is already in the error message "If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2'"

How many more times does this exact thing need to be asked and answered? (In a single day!)

@toyotaSupra Disagree. The latest version of NumPy seems to be 2.0.0, released three days ago.

@DanMašek this is Numpy's first major release since 2006. Many people will be impacted throughout the world. Duplicate and unclear questions are already closed.

Because python is unfortunately the new Perl

There are two solutions for this error:
1. downgrade your numpy to 1.26.4
pip install numpy==1.26.4

or
pip install "numpy<2.0" 

Make sure to restart your kernel after downgrading numpy


Another option is:
2. install the latest version of the module which is failing*
I had an old version of opencv-python 4.8.0.76
I was able to get this working by installing the latest version of opencv-python by
pip install opencv-python==4.10.0.84

*Some modules may still not work with numpy 2.0

'We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2'


I did reproduce the error. Indeed, the versions numpy==2.0.0 and opencv-python==4.8.0.76 are apparently not compatible.

Where did specific version of numpy == 1.26.4 come from?

@haneulkim that was the last version before numpy 2.

Save your files(if needed) and follow the drill
First try
downgrading NumPy as newer versions sometimes creates the problem
if it does not solve your issue then go for the second try
Second try
Uninstall Anaconda (if you are using it)
and install an older version of the same
as you have to install OpenCV then NumPy gets installed along with it (may happen with other packages too) and if by any chance you have NumPy already installed in the environment then remove or downgrade it and check if it works
or else go for the third try
Third try
If it still shows the issue then repeat the Second try and this time install OpenCV without any dependency
use the command below:
pip install opencv-python --no-deps
the command is to be executed in the conda terminal
Second and third tries worked for me, I did not create a new environment instead, I installed it in the base environment
I would suggest you create a new environment and install OpenCV without dependency
