# Is TensorFlow supported on M1 max?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, apple-m1

In my attempt to start using TensorFlow on my mac [Monterey 12.6.1] [chip Apple M1 MAX] I start to get errors that I did not observe on my mac mini [Monterey 12.6 - Chip M1 2020]

It is either an environment issue or a chipset issue.
[Works on my windows machine Win-11 and Mac-Mini]

Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = Sequential([layers.Input((3, 1)),
                    layers.LSTM(64),
                    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                    layers.Dense(1)])

model.compile(loss='mse', 
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=100)
```

Error observed in DataSpell:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe
```

Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
      2 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
      3 from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Following Greg Hogg tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbTU92pbDKw

Note this code work on my mac mini machine but not on the MacBook Pro.
Anaconda env -> Python 3.9

---

```
python --version
Python 3.9.12

conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow-deps           2.8.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-estimator      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-macos          2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

What I am expecting is similar outcome like the windows environment and the Mac-mini where the model is constructed and fitted with the training data. (model object creation without an exception)

Example:

```
Epoch 99/100
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.1541 - mean_absolute_error: 1.8648 - val_loss: 9.5456 - val_mean_absolute_error: 2.6235
Epoch 100/100
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 6.7555 - mean_absolute_error: 2.0134 - val_loss: 9.4403 - val_mean_absolute_error: 2.6016

<keras.callbacks.History at 0x27a6590c6a0>
```

Attempting the numpy upgrade posted answer, I did the "numpy upgrade" yet had the output below on the terminal and the same exception still observed.

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.21.5)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.23.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.21.5
    Uninstalling numpy-1.21.5:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.21.5
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
scipy 1.7.3 requires numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5, but you have numpy 1.23.4 which is incompatible.
numba 0.55.1 requires numpy<1.22,>=1.18, but you have numpy 1.23.4 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.4
```

==================================

So combination of multiple approaches fixed the issue:

1. pip uninstall keras
2. pip uninstall keras-preprocessing
3. pip uninstall tensorboard
4. pip install --upgrade numpy
5. If step 4 does not work [error or concerning warning], then pip uninstall numpy ; followed by pip install numpy
6. python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
   That fix my environment problem.

Comment: The problem is with numpy, not with tensorflow, and has nothing to do with apple processors. The problem is that you have multiple versions of numpy installed (python part vs the native numpy library, with incompatible versions).

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-a-but-this-version-of-numpy-is

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to install tensorflow-metal with tensorflow

### Requirements

- Mac computers with Apple silicon or AMD GPUs
- macOS 12.0 or later (Get the latest beta)
- Python 3.8 or later
- Xcode command-line tools: xcode-select --install

### Set up

```bash
// Download Conda environment
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps

// Install base TensorFlow
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos

// Install tensorflow-metal plug-in
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

### Verify the set up

```py
import tensorflow as tf

cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

Comment: Followed those steps but did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer to your problem though is that you have many version of numpy installed.

Please run `pip3 install --upgrade numpy` in your terminal and it should fix your problem.

Comment: The upgrade shows the following:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
scipy 1.7.3 requires numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5, but you have numpy 1.23.4 which is incompatible.

Comment: I manage to get it to work after uninstall off keras it seems I have multiple issues. and re install   tensorflow-macos

Answer (score 0):

So combination of multiple approaches fixed the issue:

1. `pip uninstall keras`
2. `pip uninstall keras-preprocessing`
3. `pip uninstall tensorboard`
4. `pip install --upgrade numpy`
5. If step 4 does not work [error or concerning warning], then `pip uninstall numpy`; followed by `pip install numpy`
6. `python -m pip install tensorflow-macos`

That fix my environment problem.