# How can I delete EVERYTHING about Python including the one provided by Mac OS X and reinstall safely?

Tags: python, macos, path, reinstall

Tl;dr I have been a dummy and messing with those things. I have been going to site_packages doing stuff I shouldn't have been doing and I have messed with my environment variables.... PATH.... PYTHONPATH.... I don't even know all of this stuff yet I have to research it more in depth. Bottom line is that when I'm trying to install a package using a package manager like pip to install opencv... it's installing fine supposedly but then I get the "no module named cv" error.

I tried importing cv and cv2.

I think I am having this problem because I have been messing with a lot of stuff I shouldn't have.

So how do I start a brand new slate?... I don't even know how many python versions I have...

Comment: This discussion may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems

Comment: Yeah thanks Andrew I've seen that already. Problem is he solved it by doing a full OS reinstall. I kind of wanted to avoid that... but I think that's what I'm going to end up doing. Sigh....

Comment: As a stop gap, try installing Anaconda. It runs as its own separate Python environment. You can use `conda install ...` to install third party packages not included in the Anaconda download.

Comment: Kind of a stop-gap, but have you tried using e.g. homebrew to install their python? I think `brew uninstall` removes everything, so doing that and reinstalling should hopefully lead to a working installation, as long as you use `/usr/local/bin/python`