# Why do I have multiple version of Python under different paths on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos-sierra

I am using `MacOS Sierra`.

For some reason, I have different Python versions under different path names. These are the directories in my **root folder**

[image]

Under **/System, I have 2 versions** (2.3 & 2.5 symlinks to -> 2.6):

```
$ ls System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 Current
```

Under **/Library, 3 versions** (7.3 is a misnamed 2.7):

```
$ ls Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.7 3.2 7.3 Current
```

Under **/Users, 1 versions**:

```
$ ls Users/mySelf/Library/Python/
3.2
```

I need to install python 3.4 but I am not sure where it should go.

Comment: Under /System, 2.3 and 2.5 are symlinks to 2.6.

Comment: Just corrected it.

Comment: I highly recommend that you don't install Python directly, but that you use a package manager such as Homebrew, Fink, MacPorts, Alt portage, or whatever. Sidestep the problem of deciding where to put a manually-installed Python, and also enable yourself to have a cleanly managed system.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Even better use pyenv this is Python's RVM it lets you install and manage multiple python versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Mac is a pain to install stuff on sometimes. Luckily for us, there is something called [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)! Homebrew is a package manager that is useful for installing many things that would otherwise be troublesome. It will even tell you where things go wrong and how to fix them (or at least start fixing them).

There is an installation guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos) or [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/) that you can follow. Happy coding :)

**Edit 1**: As to why you have multiple python versions installed, firstly mac comes with python 2.7 installed out of the box. Secondly, you may have installed another version of python at some point by accident (whether another program did it for you or it was done directly by you). You may need to go through the process of filtering out the ones you don't have any dependencies on and just delete them.

**Edit 2**: It is also worth mentioning that since El Capitan, apple introduced [System Integrity Protection](http://www.macworld.com/article/2948140/os-x/private-i-el-capitans-system-integrity-protection-will-shift-utilities-functions.html) which caused problems for many installations by locking users out of the default installation folders for packages such as python or latex. Homebrew will get you around most of this without a problem, and keep track of your installations (if installed through homebrew).

**Edit 3**: As to why there are many paths for python available it is very closely linked to [how you installed python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174029/5434676) pPackage installer, macports, homebrew all install in different locations, hence you would have a different path for each. You would probably have a few conflicting installations too.

Comment: I know there can be multiple version. I want to know why they are under different paths.

Comment: Thanks for the guides!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174029/5434676 - it will tell you exactly why. I'll put it in my answer above, then if you feel okay with it maybe choose it as the accepted answer? ;)