# installed pip package not found

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I was just given a new mac and after installing pip and lcc through pip I get a command not found error when running lcc run.

When running `help("modules")` inside of python I can see the lcc package there.

the same goes for `pip freeze`

`pip freeze | grep lemon
lemoncheesecake==0.15.2`

I'm running out of ideas.....

maybe I messed up the pip installation because I did it first with:

python get-pip.py

and then with

sudo easy_install pip

how do I fix this?

this is my `echo $PATH`
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Thanks

Comment: could you try running "python -m lcc run"

Comment: @JamesKent `/usr/bin/python: No module named lcc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're saying it seems that your python installation is not quite right, and Mac's version of python is also not quite right by default, you can read more about it here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#doing-it-right

Also, I would highly advise that when you get a brand new Mac and plan to do some development work as a rule of thumb follow these steps:

1. Install xcode
2. Install Homebrew

Then you can install anything else you want.

Comment: full format + install everything on that link = 10 hours of work...

At least is working!!!

Thank you @Marc Lopez!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the fact you have more than one version of python installed. Package installed by pip are visible to one version, but not to the other. I think this issue is quite common, and has already been answered (for example) here:

[Too many different Python versions on my system and causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems)

To check that this is the case:

```
pip show Icc
```

should tell you where Icc was installed.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

should tell where python looks for modules.