# jupyter notebook in VS code: Why can I not load library 'requests'?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, importerror

### It worked...

Im on mac OS 10.15.7 and
I have a function in a python script that needs the `requests` module. I followed the installation outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests/17309309#17309309) by user [TheoretiCAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560035/theoretical).

Last week I ran the script **successfully** from the VS code interpreter using `python3.9.1`.

### ...until it didn't:

Today I had to `import requests` in jupyter still in VS code.
The module is *not found* **despite** VS being set to

- `python3.9.1` in the lower left corner
- `pip --version` giving me:

`pip 21.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

- `import sys  print(sys.version)` giving me `3.9.1`
- Also jupyter is running the right kernel as seen in the top right corner of VS (screenshot at the bottom of the page)

Unfortunately [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896622/python-vs-code-imports-not-working-no-module-name-requests) did not help me any further either.

From my side it looks like I've done everything that is recommended. What did my tiny beginners brain miss?

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried installing it with pip, just in case it hasn't downloaded properly?

Comment: I have installed it with pip. Or do you mean I should just do it again?

Comment: Try again in jupyter notebook, `!pip3 install requests`

Comment: @ilamengl Try it again. And do what KetZoomer says.

Comment: @KetZoomer It did work! I don't understand why: I understand VS code uses whichever version of python I choose. When choosing said versions it should find the all installed modules within that version. -Correct. OR does it make a difference when running from the jupyter notebook???

Comment: What you want to check is `sys.executable`. That's the python exe you're working with.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami `'/usr/local/bin/python3'` - obviously I checked within the notebook :)

Comment: `$ /usr/local/bin/python3`  
`>>> import requests`  
does that work?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami yes, just like it worked last week. It was only when importing within the notebook, when it did not work.

Comment: There are many things that are required before one can identify what the issue is. Are you using a virtualenv/conda env and launching jupyter from within it? How many versions of python do you have installed? How many of them have requests installed? vscode shows you what kernel it's using on the top right hand corner, is it what you want it to be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232562/discussion-between-ilam-engl-and-diptangsu-goswami).

Comment: @ilamengl. Has your question been solved?

Answer (score 2):

1. After selecting interpreter, you may install the module in current environment;
2. Choose the same environment for Jupyter;
3. Use `pip show requests` to check its location. If not in current selected environment, enter the environment and reinstall it.

[image]

Comment: All I wanna do is to solve your question and I'm glad to know it's already been resolved. so, it doesn't matter if you mark my answer now. Happy Coding. :)